# Getting a input to only accept something from a string Python

Tags: python

My Python code is trying to take the inputs that the user has given and give them back but in line 5 I want the user to only be able to write either m or f and nothing else so I looked up if python had a char data type like c++ but it doesn't so I kept looking and people said that you could use strings as a data type but I don't know how to implement that so I hope you guys can help enlighten me.

Here is the link to the code the important parts are 4 and 5. What is written was more of a guess.

```
#Input your information
name = input("Enter your Name: ")
surname = input("Enter Surname: ")
str(m,f)
gender = str(input("What is your gender?(m,f)")
height = input("Enter your Height: ")
 
#Print your information
print("\n")
print("Printing Your Details")
print("Name", "Surname", "Age","Gender","Height")
print( name, surname, age, gender, height)
```

Comment: result of `input` already is of type `str`, no need to "convert" it

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user to have multiple "tries", use the if condition proposed in other answers *inside a loop*, e.g. `while True:` loop

```py
while True:
    gender = input("What is your gender?(m,f)")
    if gender in ("m","f"):
        break
    print("Invalid gender input!")
print("Gender is",gender)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. And I hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

You want to condition the input: if the the input is something, then it's okay`if not then... That's why you can use`if`statement. just ask if`gender`is`f`or`m`

```py
if gender is in ['m', 'f']
    # Valid Answer
else
    # Not Valid Answer
```

In this code I put 'm' and 'f' in a list, and ask if gender (user response) is inside the list, means if it is m or f

Edit: As suggested in comment, a better version will be:

```py
if gender.lower() in ['m', 'f']
    # Valid Answer
else
    # Not Valid Answer
```

which change `gender` to lower case and then compare it to 'm' or 'f', just to make sure you do not want case sentensive

Comment: No need for the `is`. Also, for a case like this you might want to support uppercase too, so might want to check `if gender.lower() in ['m', 'f']`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

Just check an input condition:

```py
gender = input("What is your gender?(m,f)")
if gender not in ["m", "f"]:
    print("Invalid gender input!")
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will remember this for further projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going continue asking multiple choice questions, here's a special method you may use:

```py
def choices(message, m):
    print(message)
    print('Choices:')
    for i in m:
        print(' -', i)
    while True:
        chosen = input('Input Here: ')
        if chosen in m:
            break
        print('Invalid.')
    print('Great choice:', chosen, '\n')
    return chosen


gender = choices('What is your gender?', ['m', 'f'])
color = choices('What is your favorite color?', ['red', 'green', 'blue'])
foobar = choices('Which do you use more?', ['foo', 'bar'])
```

I've also taken an artistic liberty to ask for a choice of favorite colors.

Comment: Thank you very much Ill be sure to try it out.